# Strange behavior of mouse clicking through an element 

Tags: css, click, position, opacity, css-position

I'm making a website where there's a menu, but the problem is that menu always has opacity even when the option is not included, **and when i hover over an option in it, i notice that the mouse can click on some element beneath this menu**, i don't want this to happen so how to prevent this from happening ?

As you see those two rounded check marks still can be clicked even if the menu is open.

[image]

**EDIT:**
It turned out to be `position:absolute;` that causes this problem, i have no idea why is that. Actually i'm not even sure about that. Still waiting for an answer.

And turned out too that any element in the page that has `position:absolute;` behaves the same!

```
<div class="mainTaskWrapper clearfix">
    <!-- All ID names are to be changed later on -->
    <div class="mainMarker"></div>
    <label for="task1">This is task1</label>
    <!-- holder, checkButton and optTrigger are the underneath elements -->
    <div class="holder"></div>
    <div class="subTrigger"></div>                            
    <div class="checkButton"></div>
    <div class="optTrigger"></div>
    <!-- the following is for the drop-down menu -->
    <div class="mainOptions">
        <ul>
            <li id="mainInfo">Details</li>
            <li id="mainDivide">Divide</li>
            <li id="mainEdit">Edit</li>
            <li id="mainDelete">Delete</li>
        </ul>                               
    </div>
</div>
```

And that's the styling of it :

```
//This is for the tick buttons underneath the drop-down menu    
div.holder , div.checkButton, div.optTrigger {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.2;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left:5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.checkButton {
    background: url('../img/check_checked.png') no-repeat center;
}

div.checkButton:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

div.optTrigger {
    background: url('../img/toggle_down_light.png') no-repeat center;
}

div.optTrigger:hover{
    opacity: 1.0;
}

div.optTrigger.active{  
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    background: url('../img/toggle_down_light_opened.png') no-repeat center darkslategray;
}

div.holder {
    opacity: 1.0;
    background: url('../img/holder.png') no-repeat center;
    cursor: move;
}

//The following is for the drop-down menu
.mainOptions {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    background : darkslategrey;
    opacity: 1.0;
    left : 626px;
    top:25px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
}

.mainOptions li {
    color : lightgrey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    padding:5px 15px;
    font-size : 12px;  
    cursor:pointer;
}

.mainOptions li:hover {
    background : grey;
}

.mainOptions li:last-of-type:hover{
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}

.mainOptions li:first-of-type:hover{
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.mainOptions li:last-of-type{
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: this seems to be not an opacity issue - give the elements an `opacity: 1` and see if you still can click through them

Comment: @ZoltanToth Hmm that's strange, even with `opacity:1.0` the menu looks kind of transparent, and the issue happens too. I will edit the question with the complete styling for that menu.

Comment: @Julian No, i'm doing the CSS stuff first.

Comment: can you post some code? This seems like it can be a simple fix.

Comment: Yes, question has the code now.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle with your code and i'm not seeing the transparancy issue http://jsfiddle.net/P2pVr/1/

Comment: I think the problem is caused by `position:relative;` in the parent div.

Comment: @Rafael: +1 for really spending the time to write a well-documented question.  It's nice sometimes to see someone really put an effort forth to get the help they need.

Comment: Thanks, it's kinda hard to explain the problem since English is not my native language. But i'm glad it's well understood.

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't include the tick marks on the menu next to it, so I can't see the problem in a fiddle. Can you include more code, for both the menu options?

Comment: @zenkaty Done, i've included the tick marks code.